# Magento : How to pass customer comments from product view page to cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am new to magento. 
I have to develop a module which allows the customer to enter comments in the product view page. This comment has to be further displayed in the cart and also in the order.Pls tell me how the comments entered by customer in a textarea in the product view page can be stored in the sales_flat_quote_item and can be further retrieved and displayed in the cart.
TIA.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a text area custom option.

Comment: Custom option has to be set for each product separately right?

Comment: Yes, that's the downside of this solution, unless you use a dedicated extension

Comment: Is there any other solution. I have created a text area in the addtocart.phtml to get the comment from user. Also created a field for comment in sales_flat_quote_item table. But Iam not able to save the comment value in the table. Can you pls suggest how to save the value? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Magento Provide custom options, So you can add one custom options and field type `text-area`

Thus this custom option is display in your product page and if customer can fill in the comment area customer comment can display in your cart page and on in checkout page and in order details also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want the comment area for every product. Using custom option is not a feasible solution, right?

Comment: Yes you have to define custom options for every product.